# cocos2d-js game iOS Crash when enter the game at the second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

We are using cocos2d-js to develop an iOS App which can launch different games. So I add an button in the native app viewcontroller and start the game by clicking the button, just like this:

```
-(void)didClickGame2Btn:(id)sender
{
    //加载游戏
    cocos2d::Application *app = cocos2d::Application::getInstance();
    // Initialize the GLView attributes
    app->initGLContextAttrs();
    cocos2d::GLViewImpl::convertAttrs();

    // Use RootViewController to manage CCEAGLView
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    rootViewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:rootViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    // IMPORTANT: Setting the GLView should be done after creating the RootViewController
    cocos2d::GLView *glview = cocos2d::GLViewImpl::createWithEAGLView((__bridge void *)rootViewController.view);
    cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->setOpenGLView(glview);
    NSString *documentDir = [SEGetDirectories dirDoc];
    NSString *wPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/GameData/Game2",documentDir];
    NSLog(@"document------:%@",documentDir);

    std::vector<std::string> searchPathList;
    searchPathList.push_back([wPath UTF8String]);        
    cocos2d::FileUtils::getInstance()->setSearchPaths(searchPathList);

    //run the cocos2d-x game scene
    app->run();
}];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:true];
}
```

the rootViewController contains the game view. And then we add an button in the game, which is used to exit the game. The click event code of the exit game button likes:

```
//exit the game and close the view controller
gameEndCallBack:function(sender){
    cc.log("director end............");
    cc.director.end();
    var ojb = jsb.reflection.callStaticMethod("ViewControllerUtils", "dismissCurrentVC");
}
```

We use the reflection to dismiss the rootViewController:

```
+(void)dismissCurrentVC
{
    UIViewController *currentVC = [ViewControllerUtils getCurrentVC]; //这里获取最顶层的viewcontroller
    [currentVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"xxx");
    }];
}
```

Everything is ok when the first time to enter the game, but after dismissing the rootViewController, we try to enter the game again, it crash.

The crash line is in the  ScriptingCore::runScript metod and executing the code:

```
evaluatedOK = JS_ExecuteScript(cx, global, *script, &rval);
```

And the crash info is  "exc_bad_access".

It is much the same problem as this topic, but the approaches in it did not solve the problem.
http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-destroy-a-cocos-game-on-ios-completely/23805

This problem has been confusing me serveral days,  I have no solution for this. Can anyone give me some help?

Comment: thats no reflection you are using. but thats not related. the issue seems to be that a variable you are using was allocated in between... or points at the old vc or so. Id check the 4 independently...

Answer (score 0):

You can make the app to support multiple games with in the app. 
All you have done is required but in addition to that please follow the below instructions.

First of all, cocos provide a singleton instance of `cocos2d::Application` that can not be restarted again especially in iOS. So the approach of ending the Director `cc.director.end();` won't help you.

You should start the application only once by using the function call `cocos2d::Application::getInstance()->run();` and next time if you want to start the game layer, you **should not** call this method again.

Instead, just pause `cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->pause();` and resume `cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->resume();` the director when you want to stop the game.

In this approach, if you dismiss/dealloc the view-controller instance then you **should** create the glview `cocos2d::GLView` instance again without calling the run method.

One more problem is, take care of the delay in loading the new scene. GLView will display the previous game scene for a while. Do a work around that will show blank screen while the new scene is ready.

Hope this will help you.